# How do I get a SKAction to repeat itself after a random period of time

Tags: swift, random, sprite-kit, repeat, skaction

I currently have the below code that happily repeats an action every 2 seconds, but I want it to happen at a completely random period of time, e.g sometime between 1 and 10 seconds, I tried a few different lines of code using arch4random of which none worked. I'm hoping its a simple fix, any advice is greatly appreciated.

Thanks   `runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.runBlock(callBird), SKAction.waitForDuration(2.0)])))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are trying to randomize a duration parameter, a
[+ waitForDuration:withRange:](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKAction/waitForDuration:withRange:) will do the job.

```
runAction(
            SKAction.repeatActionForever(
                SKAction.sequence([SKAction.runBlock({/*do your stuff*/}),
                   SKAction.waitForDuration(2, withRange: 3) ])))
```

From the docs :

> Each time the action is executed, the action computes a new random
>   value for the duration. The duration may vary in either direction by
>   up to half of the value of the durationRange parameter.

Means that if a duration is set to 2 and a range parameter is set to 3, a possible duration value will vary between 0.5 and 3.5.